# Upload Directory

Tags: c++, ftp, directory, uploading

How can I upload a directory using the `FtpPutFile` function or all the directory this is my code:

```
void FileSubmit(path ToUpload)
{
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);

    if (hInternet == NULL) cout << ("No Internet Connection..\n");
    else cout << ("Internet Connection Established\n");

    hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet,"host",INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "user","pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0 );
    if (!hFtpSession) cout << ("Error in the FTP connection..\n");
    else
    {
        cout <<("FTP Connection Established!\n");
        FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "D://test//*.doc", ToUpload.string().c_str(), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE);
        if (!FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "D://test//*.doc", ToUpload.string().c_str(), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE))
        cout <<("File Transfer Failed..\n");
        else cout << ("The file was sent..\n");
        InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    }
}


int main()
{
FileSubmit(destination);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'upload' directories directly; you would need to create the directory with `FtpCreateDirectory()` then iterate over all the files in your local directory and call `FtpPutFile()` on each of them.

If you need a way of getting a list of files in a directory you can use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/). Look for the `directory_iterator` and `recursive_directory_iterator` classes.

Comment: I don't need to create a directory on the host but how can I iterate over all the files in the local directory

Comment: @pourjour I've updated my answer. There will be something to do it in the Windows API if you prefer, but you will have to look that up yourself.